# SourceTree Add remote credentials to local git repo

Tags: git, push, atlassian-sourcetree

I used SourceTree (on OSX 10.11.6) to create both a local and remote repo.

I have added an SSH Key with passphase to the remote repo

I have added files to the local repo and have commited code with a good .ignore

When I try to push, I get:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.

So how do I add my access rights for the remote repo I just created into my local repo in SourceTree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I add my access rights for the remote repo I just created into my local repo in SourceTree?

Assuming you added a remote repository to your local.
If you did not add any you have to add remote:

```
 git remote add origin <url>
```

---

Verify that SourceTree is configured correctly.

Go to the settings and under git change to the `OPEN SSH` and make sure your keys are the following: `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

If you still cant connect try to start the `ssh agent`

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add -l
```

Then, check if you see your keys. if not simply add them:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: My SourceTree is set to use Embedded git, rather than System git. Does this matter? My remote git repo is in bitbucket. Does that matters? The file you mention has different contents than the pub file in SourceTree. My guess is that the file you mention is my private key, and the SSH key in SourceTree (Menu->SourceTree->Preferences->Accounts tab) under achmann_Bitbucket.pub is my public key for bitbucket? Do I have to add bitchbucket as a known host on my machine?

Comment: In my keychain, I see separate items for is_rsa and for bitbucket - does that matter? lol, all these questions

Comment: No joy. When I initially created my repo I didn't have bitbucket. I created bitbucket account after and then when creating bitbucket, it asked for an SSH passphrase for that account key. How do I sync my remote bitbucket account with my local... Just start over?

Comment: All good - I got it. What I had to do was go into my bitbucket account - Settings->SSH - add my rsa key there. - All works now

Comment: The ssh-add note did help, so I'll set it as the answer